# $compile an HTML template and perform a printing operation only after $compile is completed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In a directive link function, I want to add to document's DIV a compiled ad-hoc template and then print the window. I try the following code and printer preview appears, but the data in preview is still not compiled.

```
// create a div
printSection = document.createElement('div');
printSection.id = 'printSection';
document.body.appendChild(printSection);

// Trying to add some template to div
scope.someVar = "This is print header";
var htmlTemplate = "<h1>{{someVar}}</h1>"; 
var ps = angular.element(printSection);
ps.append(htmlTemplate);
$compile(ps.contents())(scope);

// What I must do to turn information inside printSection into compiled result 
// (I need later to have a table rendered using ng-repeat?)

window.print();
// ... currently shows page with "{{someVar}}", not "This is print header"
```

Is it also so that $compile is not synchronous? How I can trigger window.print() only after it finished compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to finish the current digestion process to be able to print

so changing

```
window.print();
```

to

```
_.defer(function() {
    window.print();
});
```

or $timeout, or any deferred handler.

will do the trick.

The other way (probably the 'right' approach) is to force the newly compilated content's watchers to execute before exiting the current $apply phase :

```
module.factory("scopeUtils", function($parse) {

        var scopeUtils = {

            /**
             * Apply watchers of given scope even if a digest progress is already in process on another level.
             * This will only do a one-time cycle of watchers, without cascade digest.
             *
             * Please note that this is (almost) a hack, behaviour may be hazardous so please use with caution.
             *
             * @param {Scope} scope : scope to apply watchers from.
             */
            applyWatchers : function(scope) {
                scopeUtils.traverseScopeTree(scope, function(scope) {
                    var watchers = scope.$$watchers;
                    if(!watchers) {
                        return;
                    }
                    var watcher;
                    for(var i=0; i<watchers.length; i++) {
                        watcher = watchers[i];
                        var value = watcher.get(scope);
                        watcher.fn(value, value, scope);
                    }
                });
            },

            traverseScopeTree : function(parentScope, traverseFn) {
                var next,
                    current = parentScope,
                    target = parentScope;
                do {
                    traverseFn(current);

                    if (!(next = (current.$$childHead ||
                        (current !== target && current.$$nextSibling)))) {
                        while(current !== target && !(next = current.$$nextSibling)) {
                            current = current.$parent;
                        }
                    }
                } while((current = next));
            }

        };

        return scopeUtils;
    });
```

use like this :

```
scopeUtils.applyWatchers(myFreshlyAddedContentScope);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks but it won't work:                var a;
                $timeout(function () {
                    a = $compile(ps.contents())(scope);

                    
                }).then(function () {
                    ps = a;
                    window.print();
                }); - still getting uncompiled result.

Comment: compile before the timeout. only the print() code in the timeout. else you are STILL in the same digest cycle.

Comment: in my case it started to work such as:                 $compile(ps.contents())(scope);
                scope.$digest();
                $timeout(function () {
                }, 0, true).then(function () {
                    window.print();
                });

Comment: it didnt work without the "scope.$digest()" between the $compile and the $timeout ?

Comment: Well, that is my impression. :)